# Addition is performed in three tables and their difference is updated in one of the table

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to perform addition into the tables

Table - A

````
```
SELECT Unit, group, City, startdate, sum(Amt)
FROM gmr.BFR_CAL 
Group By unit, group, city, startdate
```
sample data:-

tyre    mrf   hyder     12-04-23  49

Table - B

```
SELECT Unit, group, City, startdate, sum(Amt) 
FROM gmr.DRAFT 
WHERE ty = 6
Group By unit, group, city, startdate

```

sample data:-

tyre    mrf   hyder     12-04-23  5


Table - C
```
SELECT Unit, group, City, startdate, sum(Amt) 
FROM gmr.DRAFT 
WHERE  ty <> 6
Group By unit, group, city, startdate;
```
sample data:-

tyre    mrf   hyder     12-04-23  18
````

Need the query with

B+C != A then

update AMT(column) of B(table) with type=6

And Update equation will be

```
AMT= A-"B+C"
AMT=49-(18+5)
AMT=49-23
AMT= 26
```

So
Update should be happend in col(Amt) in Table B where previous amt was 5, but now for table B instead of amt=5 now it should be amt=26.

```
Finally Table B should look like :-

tyre    mrf   hyder     12-04-23  26
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. We have no data nor the expected outcome of said data to work with. Which rows need updating and how; does every row in `gmr.BFR_CAL` need to have the amount amending by the total, or does the total need to be spread across the rows? (I.e. if the total is 10 and there are 10 rows to update, do we remove 10 from each row, or remove 1 from each row?). Which rows in `gmr.draft` need to be updated? The `ty = 6` rows, the `ty <> 6` rows, or all of them? Please edit your question to include sample data and the expected result of that data.

Comment: In Table gmr.draft for ty=6 and ty<>6 both needs to update. and in all the tables major role in the changes is in only one column that is AMT (col)

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data from both tables, plus the output you expect to see in both tables following the updates.

Comment: Edited, please let me know if any more cleaity required.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data in both your tables and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: I edited, Please let me know if more clearity needed or anything i'm missing.Help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement. You have only vaguely described your tables and how you want to join the tables and correlate the update but you appear to want something like:

```sql
MERGE INTO gmr.DRAFT dst
USING (
  SELECT a.unit,
         a.group_name,
         a.city,
         a.startdate,
         a.total,
         bc.total6,
         bc.totalNot6
  FROM   (
           SELECT Unit,
                  group_name,
                  City,
                  startdate,
                  sum(Amt) AS total
           FROM   gmr.BFR_CAL 
           GROUP BY
                  unit,
                  group_name,
                  city,
                  startdate
         ) a
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT Unit,
                  group_name,
                  City,
                  startdate,
                  SUM(CASE WHEN ty =  6 THEN amt END) AS total6,
                  SUM(CASE WHEN ty <> 6 THEN amt END) AS totalNot6
           FROM   gmr.DRAFT
           Group By
                  unit,
                  group_name,
                  city,
                  startdate
         ) bc
         ON (   a.unit       = bc.unit
            AND a.group_name = bc.group_name
            AND a.city       = bc.city
            AND a.startdate  = bc.startdate )
) src
ON (   src.unit       = dst.unit
   AND src.group_name = dst.group_name
   AND src.city       = dst.city
   AND src.startdate  = dst.startdate )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET amt = (total + total6) - (total6 + totalNot6);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE gmr.DRAFT (unit, group_name, city, startdate, ty, amt) AS
SELECT 'unit1', 'grp1', 'city1', DATE '1970-01-01', 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'unit1', 'grp1', 'city1', DATE '1970-01-01', 2, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'unit1', 'grp1', 'city1', DATE '1970-01-01', 3, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'unit1', 'grp1', 'city1', DATE '1970-01-01', 6, 400 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE gmr.BFR_CAL (unit, group_name, city, startdate, amt) AS
SELECT 'unit1', 'grp1', 'city1', DATE '1970-01-01', 1000 FROM DUAL;
```

After the `MERGE` then:

```
SELECT * FROM gmr.DRAFT;
```

Outputs:

| UNIT | GROUP_NAME | CITY | STARTDATE | TY | AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| unit1 | grp1 | city1 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 400 |
| unit1 | grp1 | city1 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 400 |
| unit1 | grp1 | city1 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 400 |
| unit1 | grp1 | city1 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 6 | 400 |

And the values have all been updated to the new total amount.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EYZwiA56)

Comment: Getting error that amt can't be updated because there is only one column in the table which is going to update but here you have taken total6,totalnot6 and total which is causiing issue

Comment: @Umesh As I commented on the question, please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data in both your tables and the expected output for that sample data. If you do not tell us what data you are starting with and what you expect the output to be then you will find that either: you do not get answers; or the answers make up the data and it may not match your issue. So help us to help you and give us a complete [MRE].

Answer (score -2):

Use buffer table, temporary table to make calculation and then you can add row or update. Then you can truncate and drop buffer, temporary table.